# Как определить, что массивы равны

Tags: google-apps-script

Создаю 2 массива, считывая **один и тот же (!)** набор ячеек на листе spreadsheet. Но при сравнении эти массивы почему-то оказываются **не равны** друг другу.

```
  var sm = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  var arr1 = sm.getRange(2, 1, 1, 2).getValues();
  var arr2 = sm.getRange(2, 1, 1, 2).getValues();

  if(arr1 == arr2) {
    Logger.log("equal");
  } else {
    Logger.log("not equal");
  }
```

Результат ***"not equal"***.

Но почему?!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В JS массивы являются объектами. Они ссылаются на разные области памяти, т.о. неравны.

Минимальный код для сравнения

```
if(JSON.stringify(arr1) === JSON.stringify(arr2)) ...
```